# Junit tests for @ConditionalOnClass and @ConditionalOnBean annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have my config class as shown below

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({SomeKeyService.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SomeConfig.class})
public class MyServiceAutoConfig {

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("certificate.password")
@ConditionalOnBean(KeyStore.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public someClass myService(KeyStore ks, SomeConfig config) {
return new someClass(ks, config.getPassword());
}
```

```
public class MyServiceAutoConfigTest{
ApplicationRunner context = new ApplicationRunner().withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(MyServiceAutoConfig.class));

@Test
public void givenPropertyShouldHaveSomeClassBean() {
this.context.withUserConfiguration(MyServiceAutoConfig.class, SomeConfig.class)
.withPropertyValues("certificate.password=hdgjashjfdjcn")
.run((context) -> {assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(someClass.class);});
}
```

> someClass implements SomeKeyService and KeyStore is java.security.KeyStore.

> Error: no beans found of that type.

My question is, How do i test these @Conditionals?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've already found `ApplicationContextRunner`, but it can do a lot more than you've shown here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-runner contains quite some examples.

What I've used myself mostly:

- For `@ConditionalOnClass`, use `FilteredClassLoader` (see the above URL)
- For `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` and `@ConditionalOnBean`, create a custom bean provider class that you include additionally using `withUserConfiguration`
- For `@ConditionalOnProperty`, specify these using `withPropertyValues`
- For `@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint` and `@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator`, just add the necessary properties to enable the endpoint or health indicator

Comment: i have tried the suggestions mentioned above, nothing seems to work, could you share sample code.

Comment: You can check my unit tests: https://github.com/robtimus/connect-sdk-java-spring-boot-starter/tree/master/src/test/java/com/github/robtimus/connect/sdk/java/springboot/autoconfigure